# trying to create contract on anvil/forge get error intrinsic gas too high

Tags: gas, forge, anvil

exact message:

message: intrinsic gas too high -- CallGasCostMoreThanGasLimit, data: None

generic counter contract from how to. googling around got me some old error somewhat related but not sure whether they are same thing.
thanks!

here is anvil log:

```
eth_chainId
eth_getTransactionCount
eth_getBlockByNumber
eth_feeHistory
eth_estimateGas
```

Answer (score 0):

So I figured that you can do `anvil -a 12` to create a batch of 12 for wallets to use to do things like create contracts.

Comment: Please, how does that answer and actually solve your question?

Comment: I think what Pavel meant with this answer is, after doing `anvil -a N` and you get a bunch of privates with gases. Then you can use `--private-key` to use those addresses.